# @Cacheable does not work when call is made from gRPC Client

Tags: java, caching, microservices, grpc, hazelcast

I have 2 micro-service applications which connect with gRPC .I have implemented Hazelcast caching and have connected both applications to Hazelcast cache over TCP/IP.I have exposed same functionality in gRPC server using REST api as well as accessing the same from gRPC Client using gRPC call.Caching works properly when REST api of application which also acts as gRPC Server is hit.However Caching does not work when call is made by applications which also acts as gRPC Client using gRPC call.

Please help with this

Comment: @noctarius  can u guys please have a look at this?

Comment: @pveentjer can u guys please have a look at this?

Comment: @Neil Stevenson can u guys please have a look at this?